# How to add buttons to a ListBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, listbox

In my project, I'm adding a ListBox whose items are retrieved from a database. What I want to do is to add a button to the right of each item on the ListBox that, when pressed, deletes that item from the database and refreshes the ListBox.

Now, getting the button to do that will be easy (quite possibly a `Click()` event on the button), but my problem is that I can't find a way to actually add a button to the ListBox.

Does anyone know how to do this?

BTW this is in a VB desktop app project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataGridView would be an easier solution, it already includes all the functionality you require. Simply add a text column and a button column, then you can subscribe to the Cell ContentClick event For example:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    'your database code here
    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an article on the msdn about putting controls into DataGridViews. Check this out and see if it gets you any closer to what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx

Comment: Any reason why not simply suggesting the DataGridView which is (afaik) meant for exactly such kind of scenarios?

Comment: @igrimpe. No particular reason. He'd just have to mess around making the datagridview look and feel like a list box. This could be fiddly which is why I suggest looking for something that already exists.

Comment: @igrimpe. On reflection, there is an msdn article on exactly this subject, so it may not be so fiddly after all. I've amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'll take a good reading to this, it's a great starting point. Thanks.